# How safe is it to store sensitive app data in iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

I wish to store sensitive data of my app in iCloud so that it could be accessed by one of my other apps. The information I would like to store is the levels in the game finished by the player, in-app purchase identifiers, etc. which I want to make sure, will not be modified by the user himself. Is it possible to save sensitive app data in iCloud without any legitimate way for the user to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in iCloud is no more secure against this kind of tampering than any other data stored by you app. Maybe less. It's just as accessible on the device as non-iCloud data. Also, if the user has a Mac that uses the same iCloud account, all the data gets synced there as well (yes, even though it's an iOS app). If the user edits the data on their Mac, it'll sync right back to their iOS devices.